# How to debug a DYLIB in XCode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, dylib

I am an experienced Visual Studio developer who has recently taken on an OSX 10.6 project (a C++ server project with no UI).

I have been successfully debugging the application using the XCode debugger (setting breakpoints, etc.) for months, including debugging the source code for various static libraries that are linked into the final executable program.

However, tonight I was required to debug (with breakpoints) a DYLIB that is also built from our source code, but that is linked dynamically at runtime with the application (the name of the DYLIB is read from an .ini file by the main application).

Unfortunately, the usual method I use of debugging the application (right-clicking the custom executable and selecting "Debug with Breakpoints"), though it does successfully run the debugger and allow me to debug the application (along with its statically linked libraries), exhibits the following undesired behavior when I attempt to hit a breakpoint in the source code for the DYLIB:

-> The XCode debugger reports that the breakpoint was hit in the sense that I see the function and line number in the status bar at the bottom of the XCode windows (along with an indication that this is a gdb message), and the application halts execution.  However, there is no stack trace, no variables, nothing - just a completely empty debugger window.  The buttons to to "step over", "step into", etc, are disabled.  No editor window appears in the debugger (and hence no visual indication that the debugger has stopped on the line indicated).  Opening the file by hand does not reveal the debugger hitting the line.

Unfortunately, this is useless for me as far as my attempts to debug the DYLIB.

I have hunted far and wide tonight researching and attempting to find a way for the XCode debugger to successfully hit breakpoints in a meaningful way in the source code for this dynamically linked DYLIB.  I have of course done a number of clean/rebuilds.  I have made certain that "load symbols lazily" is unchecked and then cleaned/rebuilt.  I have restarted, and I have also deleted the "build" directory and rebuilt.  I also deleted the user-specific files in the .xcodeproj package.  (Note also that I am of course building and running all code, including the DYLIB code, in Development mode with all optimizations off, and generating debug symbols for all.)  However, my attempts have been unsuccessful.  Nor can I find so much as a single mention of this problem on internet forums.

Any help in instructing me how to use XCode to successfully debug a DYLIB that is linked to my application would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Given I've done much the same thing. With no trouble. All I can suggest is your problem is much the same as it would have been in DevStudio: your dylibs have no debug symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update -

This problem is resolved.  It was my lack of experience with OSX that caused me to fail to see this.  Despite the fact that my DYLIB project was part of the same XCode project as the executable that calls it, and despite the fact that the DYLIB was built in the same directory as the executable, at runtime the debugged application was not accessing the DYLIB from this location.  Instead, it was accessing it from a (different) install location.  I have not as of this moment tracked down where the install location is "cooked" into the application, but by copying the final executable/DYLIB into the expected install location and creating a new custom executable that points to the executable in this location, debugging of both the DYLIB and the executable works.

Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: The dynamic libraries on Mac embedded the path where they need to be searched, and this path is copied into the executable during the linking. The path can be queried with `otool -D libfile.dylib`.

Comment: from running `otool -D` `-D print shared library id name` how does printing the _id_ name reveal whether a dylib is compiled with debug symbols or not?